# Rewrite a shared URL to act like the actual URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi I have been trying to get my shared SSL URL to work with my website so I can use the shared SSL certificate but I am unable to find the right information, I would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

I believe I have www.example.com internally redirected to a folder called "public" and shared.ssl-example-url.com/example.com/ is the shared SSL URL that I need to redirect to the same folder called "public" but at the moment it just produces a 404 when accessing any pages deeper than root

This is my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.co.uk$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.co.uk$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

I should mention that I have a custom mvc website.

Comment: What does your error logs say?

Comment: My logs don't display in the control panel for the shared hosting when the last two lines are used. The website needs the root to be rewritten to a folder called "public" or in the example above a folder called "folder" the above example does redirect all root requests to the right folder without displaying it in the url but it doesn't when calling it from the shared url.

Comment: `RewriteRule (.*) folder/$1 [L]` this will cause an infinite loop which is why it stops working.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I've just answered the question, check out the answer its an awesome bit of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now found the answer, I found it when trying to find how to make the website directory independent. In my case I had to amend my .htaccess file in the root directory (/html_public/) of my website as follows

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.co\.uk$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.co\.uk$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^shared\.ssl-example-url\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /example.com/public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Then in the folder called "public" I had to create another .htaccess file with this bit of code in it

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
RewriteRule ^.*$ %2index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Just thought I'd add where I got this second bit of code as its a good resource for advanced rewrites

http://www.zeilenwechsel.de/it/articles/8/Using-mod_rewrite-in-.htaccess-files-without-knowing-the-RewriteBase.html